# Why do my unit tests (mostly) fail when I select Run All but then pass when I only run one at a time?

Tags: unit-testing

I am working in Visual Studio 2013, and most of my unit tests will fail if I select "Run All", but if I select a failed test and then run it by itself, it passes. Additionally, if I select some of these tests and run them, the first test to run will pass and the others will fail. However, each will pass if run alone.

I've noticed that most of the failed tests have a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..", but again, this only appears if I run all tests.

I could run these tests one at a time, but I would very much like to avoid that. If anyone has encountered this problem before, how did you fix it?

Context: Running this in Visual Studios 2013 with .Net 4.6.2 installed.

Update: There is a test initializer running before every test that sets the state for the test environment. There is also a dispose method that runs after every test to clean that environment up.

Now, what I see happening is that there's one object in particular that does not exist before the first pass on the test initializer, but it does exist afterwards. In the cleanup after the first test, most other objects are deleted, but this one just becomes null. On the second (and all later passes) through the test initializer - so just before any actual test beyond the first - that object remains 'null' rather than getting a filepath like it did on the first pass.

Then, whenever any of those other tests try to call that object, they're getting a null value and throwing that exception.

Comment: Check if you are setting a class level object to null and then using it in a later tests. That would be my guess without looking at code

Comment: @WebDever That seems to be the case. There's an object that the cleanup method is disposing that isn't getting reset after the first test, so everything else gets the System.NullRefernceException. If you want to post this as an answer, I can wait before closing this.

Comment: Posted as answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are setting a class level object to null and then using it in a later tests.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I can only take a guess, so here it is.

You are initializing your objects inside the test class's constructor instead of in the setup method. This means that multiple tests are using the same objects at the same time and those objects can be any any state that the other tests put them in.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a static method to dispose of the null object after each test. I made that method thread safe by checking if it was in use, locking it, and then checking again to see if it is in use.

Now, whenever the testInitializer is run again, that object gets created and pointed towards the proper path, rather than simply remaining null.